# What is this encoding and how can I encode a string to it in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have an input like this:

```
$input = 'GFL/R&D/50/67289';
```

I am trying to get to this:

```
GFL$2fR$26D$2f50$2f67289
```

So far, the closest I have come is this:

```
echo filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW)
```

which produces:

```
GFL%2FR%26D%2F50%2F67289
```

How can I get from the given input to the desired output and what sort of encoding is the result in?

*By the way, please note the case sensitivity going on there. `$2f` is required rather than `$2F`.*

Comment: no idea, but worst case you could try a simple `str_replace('%', '$', $str)`

Comment: @MarcB it won't work because of the case sensitivity issue - filter var uppercases the result so I'm not sure I could reliably find the parts of the result that are encoded values in order to lowercase just those parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick: url-encode, then lower-case the encoded sequences and swap `%` for `$` with a preg callback (PHP's PCRE doesn't support case-shifting modifiers):

```
$input = 'GFL/R&D/50/67289';
echo preg_replace_callback('/(%)([0-9A-F]{2})/', function ($m) {
    return '$' . strtolower($m[2]);
}, urlencode($input));
```

output:

```
GFL$2fR$26D$2f50$2f67289
```

Comment: Although I am still curious as to whether it was a particular encoding that was being used, or just a bastardised version of urlencode.